# Selenium WebDriver and Java Robot Class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I want to use the Java Robot class in order to move the mouse over a link to dynamically create more content. For the web interactions I use the Selenium WebDriver.

```
    Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='1234']/a")).getLocation();
    Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY()+120);
    } catch (AWTException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Selenium throws an error for the getLocation function:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot determine size of element
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

mouseover action you can achieve ([Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class) without using Robot also.

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='1234']/a"))).perform();
```

include below import statement in your file.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Comment: Sorry but I need Robot because Actions is not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make a mouse movement on the page, Selenium interactions can help you do the same.

Here is the sample code for you

```
WebElement myLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='1234']/a"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(myLink).build().perform();

// if you want to click on the link : 
act.click(myLink).build().perform();

// if you want to move to the element and then click onthe link : 
act.moveToElement(myLink).click(myLink).build().perform();

// or can be done in two different steps like this : 
act = act.moveToElement(myLink);
act.click(myLink).build().perform()
```

For doing this we should import **org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;**

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work for me. Please check

```
Point p = webele.getLocation();
int x = p.getX();
int y = p.getY();
Dimension d = webele.getSize();
int h = d.getHeight();
int w = d.getWidth();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x + (w/2), y+(h/2) +80);
```